# Is it possible to do custom grouping in the ASP.NET ListView control?

Tags: asp.net, listview

You can only define a GroupItemCount in the ListView, but what if you want to do grouping based on a property of the items in the data source? Sort of an ad-hoc group by. The data source is sorted on this property.

I have seen some examples where some markup in the ItemTemplate was conditionally show, but I want to leverage the GroupTemplate if possible.

Is this possible?

Comment: By the way, I'm not looking for code, just a pointer in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

When I had to add basic group headings in a repeater I did so with a Literal control in the ItemTemplate:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<%# GetGroupHeading(Eval("Group")) %>' />
```

The 'GetGroupHeading' method in the code kept track of the previous group heading and sent back '<h2>Group Name</h2>', or an empty string if we were on the same group as the previous item. As I said though, I did this on a Repeater, so not sure if it will cover what you need for a ListView.

Comment: You can do that in a ListView as well, but adding a header is different from grouping with the GroupTemplate in the ListView control. With the GroupTemplate you can surround the items with the markup in the template. Except all you can group by is count as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

Yes Nick gave a great lead. Here's my code-behind

```
Dim sCategory_Descr As String
Function GetGroupHeading(ByVal sGroupName As String) As String
    Dim sReturn As String
    If sCategory_Descr <> sGroupName Then
        sCategory_Descr = sGroupName
        sReturn = "<H5>Category: " & UCase(sGroupName) & "</H5>"
    Else
        sReturn = ""
    End If
        Return sReturn
End Function
```

And my item_template

```
<ItemTemplate>                    
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color:#ccc;" colspan="2" id="tdCategory_Placeholder" runat="server" >
            <asp:Label Font-Bold="true"  ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text='<%# GetGroupHeading(Eval("Category_Descr")) %>' /> 
        </td>
    </tr>                                     
    <tr>
        <td > 
            <asp:DynamicControl1 />                     
        </td>                                               
        <td > 
            <asp:DynamicControl2 />
        </td>                     
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```