# Select grouped data and bind it to listview/gridview best practice

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, t-sql

What would be the best way if you have grouped data for example : (I have simplyfied everything for this example)

Item category table:

```
itemId itemCategoryId itemName
1      1              item1
2      1              item2
3      2              item3
4      1              item4
5      3              item5
```

and category table

```
itemCategoryId itemCategory
1              category1
2              category2
3              category3
```

So if I select all items I will get result same as first table(maybe with itemCategory ...)

but when I bind everything in Listview/Gridview or enything else I want to group items in categorys so if I have the same data as above my result in Listview/gridview ... should look like :

```
category1:
  1 item1
  2 item2
  4 item4
category2:
  3 item3
category3:
  5 item5
```

What do you think is the best way to do this. I am using sql-server 2008 and visual studio 2010 ASP.NET c#. Thanks for your help

I wan`t to have result from database suitable for this class:

```
public class Item
{
    public int itemId { get; set; }
    public string itemName { get; set; }

    public Item() { }

    public Item(int itemId, string itemName) 
    {
        this.itemId = itemId;
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }
}

public class GroupOfitems
{
    public string itemCategory{ get; set; }
    public List<Item> itemList { get; private set; }

    public GroupOfitems()
    {
        itemList = new List<Item>();
    }

    public GroupOfitems(string itemCategory, List<Item> itemList)
    {
        this.itemCategory= itemCategory;
        this.itemList = itemList;
    }
}
```

so I can save the data from above tables in GroupOfItems class...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend use of the ListView, there is more support for grouping. In your SELECT query you should group rows by 'itemCategory'. [See this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for details of how to declare the ListView in your code.

Comment: I can`t make group by itemCategory because the same category contains more items. This listview grouping is not the right answer for me. With group template you can make your items in listview looks like groups but every item is one group. I want to have more items in same group(based on result data). So this is not the answer I was looking for

Comment: Granted, you will need to write some custom code, but the ListView is absolutely suitable for what you want to achieve. This very topic has received various coverage on this site and other blogs, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936459/is-it-possible-to-do-custom-grouping-in-the-asp-net-listview-control), [link](http://highoncoding.com/Articles/607_Grouping_Data_in_the_ListView__Control.aspx)