# How to use the Eval function in asp.net list view group template

Tags: asp.net, listview

How do I fill the Database value using eval in group template in asp.net list view?

When I use the eval function, it's not showing any value in asp.net page.

```
 <GroupTemplate>
     <div class="box" runat="server">
         <div class="box-heading" runat="server">
             <%# Eval("menuname") %>
             <a runat="server" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 13px;" href="http://opencartwork.com/wide/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=57">
              view all
             </a>
         </div>
         <div runat="server" id="carousel10">
             <ul runat="server" class="jcarousel-skin-opencart">
                 <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="myitem"></asp:PlaceHolder>
             </ul>
         </div>
         </div>
         <script type="text/javascript">
             <!--
             $('#carousel10 ul').jcarousel({
                 vertical: false,
                 visible: 4,
                 scroll: 3
             });
             //-->
         </script>
    </GroupTemplate>
```

Comment: Can you show your code so I can see what your doing?

Comment: i added code in question

Comment: Why not put the box-heading div in the itemtemplate?

Comment: because i want to use  group of li in item template which show 10 product and then show category heading again group of li in item template.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can use eval in the GroupTemplate.

However, you can use this workaround from a previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936459/is-it-possible-to-do-custom-grouping-in-the-asp-net-listview-control).

In summary a server side method keeps track of the category heading, if this changes then the new category will be displayed in the ItemTemplate.

Comment: Edit your question and show your solution so other people can use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
                   <asp:Repeater ID="menuID" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="menuID_ItemDataBound">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <li id="menu-item-119" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-page-ancestor current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current-page-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-119">
                            <a runat="server" id="lnkbtn" title='<%# Eval("masterurl") %>'>
                                <%# Eval("menuname") %></a>
                            <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="submenu">
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <li id="menu-item-259" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-page-ancestor current-page-parent menu-item-259">
                                        <a id="A1" runat="server" href='<%# "~/"+ Eval("suburl") %>'>
                                            <%# Eval("menuname") %></a></li>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    </ul>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```